# Custom Drop down search won't allow me to add new items when using DataTables

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I have created an HTML page with a static HTML table using DataTables, a category dropdown search box, and a text field search box. Everything works fine except when I try to add new categories besides the original 3 (Category 1, Category 2, Category 3). Each of these searches and filters the table correctly. However, if I add a new category (Draw), it tells me "no entries found" even though I tagged several rows of data with the new category. If I change one of the old category option values (Category 3 for example) to "Draw", it will filter the table and show all rows with td items tagged with Category 3. Why isn't the table accepting the new dropdown options and/or not finding the new options in the table?

HTML:

```
<section id="autocad-table">
            <div class="table-container">
                <div class="category-filter">
                    <label for="Category">What Type Of Code Do You Need?</label>
                    <select class="dropdown" name="Category" id="categoryFilter">
                        <option value="">All</option>
                        <option value="1">Category 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Category 2</option>
                        <option value="3">Category 3</option>
                        <option value="4">Draw</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <table id="commandsTable" class="stripe hover">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Command</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="commandsTableBody">
                        <tr>
                            <td>0_FILLET</td>
                            <td>Create a 0" radius fillet</td>
                            <td>Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ALLFLAT</td>
                            <td>Flatten all objects in all blocks & layouts</td>
                            <td>Category 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ANNO_TO_SQUEEZE</td>
                            <td>Convert an annotation to the SQUEEZE text style</td>
                            <td>Category 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ARR</td>
                            <td>Creates an array of a selected object at a specified angle</td>
                            <td>Category 2, Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ATC</td>
                            <td>Changes an arc into a circle</td>
                            <td>Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>BA</td>
                            <td>Bend Allowance</td>
                            <td>Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>BB</td>
                            <td>BOM Ball</td>
                            <td>Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>BC</td>
                            <td>Add 'BC' to dimensions</td>
                            <td>Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CENT</td>
                            <td>Change Entities</td>
                            <td>Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CH</td>
                            <td>CHPROP</td>
                            <td>Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CO</td>
                            <td>COPY</td>
                            <td>Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>COPLAY</td>
                            <td>Sets current layer to that of a selected entity</td>
                            <td>Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CREATE_BOUNDARY</td>
                            <td>Creates a boundary (polyline) from objects made with CVFLAT-D or NTFLAT-D</td>
                            <td>Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CS</td>
                            <td>Copies items on a selected layer</td>
                            <td>Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CSM</td>
                            <td>Copies items on multiple selected layers</td>
                            <td>Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CVEDGE</td>
                            <td>Draws edges for a Curve section. Uses Command line prompting.</td>
                            <td>Draw</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CVEDGE-D</td>
                            <td>Using a dialog box, draws all edges of a Curve section and dimensions</td>
                            <td>Draw</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CVFLAT</td>
                            <td>Draws the flat views (with holes) of plates used for covers, dividers, and bottoms of curved conveyor sections</td>
                            <td>Draw</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CVFLAT-D</td>
                            <td>Similar to CVFLAT, but uses a dialog box and can draw multiple views with dimensions</td>
                            <td>Draw</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CV_CLEANOUTFLAT (CVCO)</td>
                            <td>Develop flat bar for self-cleaning Tails.</td>
                            <td>Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CWEIGHT</td>
                            <td>Weight calculator for carbon steel</td>
                            <td>Category 3, Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>DC</td>
                            <td>Dimension Circle - dimension alignment guide</td>
                            <td>Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>DD</td>
                            <td>DIMSTYLE</td>
                            <td>Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>DF</td>
                            <td>Double Fillet - Fillets the inside and outside of a corner</td>
                            <td>Category 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>DXW</td>
                            <td>NMC_DxfOut - shortcut for main command</td>
                            <td>Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>DYNOFF</td>
                            <td>Dynamic Offset</td>
                            <td>Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>EP</td>
                            <td>EXPLODE</td>
                            <td>Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ES</td>
                            <td>Erases items on a selected layer</td>
                            <td>Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>F_LINE</td>
                            <td>Reliance Electric Firstline Bearing Templates</td>
                            <td>Category 1, Category 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>GA</td>
                            <td>Add 'GA' to dimensions</td>
                            <td>Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>H</td>
                            <td>Draws a standard hole side view</td>
                            <td>Draw</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>LD2MLD</td>
                            <td>Changes selected Leader and MText into a MultiLeader</td>
                            <td>Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>LF</td>
                            <td>Changes selected dimensions' length factor to 0.25</td>
                            <td>Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>MI</td>
                            <td>MIRROR</td>
                            <td>Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>MLL</td>
                            <td>Makes a custom layer selected from a list and sets it current</td>
                            <td>Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>MOS</td>
                            <td>Moves items on a selected layer</td>
                            <td>Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>NMC_LoadDwgs</td>
                            <td>Load (open) the list of drawings previously saved with NMC_SaveDwgs</td>
                            <td>Draw</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>NMC_Object_Property_Correction (NOPC)</td>
                            <td>Corrects select object properties to match NMS layer standards. </td>
                            <td>Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>NMC_SaveDwgs</td>
                            <td>Save the currently open drawings to a list</td>
                            <td>Category 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>OH</td>
                            <td>Offset objects to HIDDEN layer</td>
                            <td>Category 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>OO</td>
                            <td>Offset an object and then delete it</td>
                            <td>Category 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ZW</td>
                            <td>ZOOM Window</td>
                            <td>Category 1</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Javascript:

```
//This was coded using the DataTable jQuery library
```

$(document).ready( function () { //load the document
var oTable = $('#commandsTable').DataTable( { //build the table
"paging":   false,
"ordering": false,
"info":     false,
"searchHighlight": true,
});

```
 $('#categoryFilter').change(function () { //check the status of the drop down menu and filter accordingly
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    oTable.column(2).search(selectedValue).draw();
})

$('input[type=search]').addClass('search-box'); //add class to DataTable search box
$('.search-box').after('<button class="close-icon" type="reset"></button>'); //add reset button to search box

$('.close-icon').hide(); //set close button to be hidden as default

//Check if the box is empty
$('.search-box').on("input", function() {
    var searchValue = $(this).val(); //store search box value as a variable
    if(searchValue != "") { //if search field is not empty, show the reset button
        $('.close-icon').show();
    } else {
        $('.close-icon').hide();
    };
});

$('.close-icon').click(function() { //clicking the reset button clears the field
    $('.close-icon').hide(); //hide reset button
    oTable.columns().every(function() { //set search field to "empty"
        this.search('');
    });
    oTable.search('').draw(); //if search field is empty, redraw the table
});
```

} );

Please let me know if you need any clarification. I also apologize if the formatting of the code is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option value is currently set as follows:

```
<option value="4">Draw</option>
```

That means your code is using the value `4` for its searches. Change the option to this:

```
<option value="Draw">Draw</option>
```

The following line is an example of extracting the `value` attribute from the `option` element:

```
var searchValue = $(this).val();
```

Note that `val()` - which is what retrieves the value, not the visible label.

(Bear in mind also that when you select `Category 1` you are only searching for `1`, and so on. If you had `Alt. Category 1` as a possible value, that would interfere with your filter, also. You may want to clean up the other option values, so that each value exactly matches the label.)

Comment: *bangs head against desk* Duh. I should have known. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am familiar with that feeling. By the way, if you want to use the labels, you can use `text()` instead of `val()`.

Comment: I did not know about the text(). Thank you!